# How to reset the sar date

Tags: bash, unix, sar

For some time now, when i run

```
sar -A
```

The header day is off 1. The system date is correct so im not sure why.

A colleague recommended resetting sar date, but imn not sure how. Is there a process related to sar that needs restarting?

Comment: StackOverflow is only for programming questions. Try `https://superuser.com` maybe. Also, identify your operating system.

Comment: Have you read the `sar` manpage on your system?